# i was implementing live streaming with agora .getting acception due to depencies versions of agora_rtc_engine: and agora_uikit:

Tags: flutter, dart, dependencies, agora.io

[image]
My pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  google_sign_in:
  firebase_core:
  firebase_auth:
  agora_rtc_engine: ^4.0.1
  permission_handler:
  agora_uikit: ^1.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_lints:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

I tried changing the versios of  agora_rtc_engine: 6.0.0 to 4.0.1 and agora_uikit: to 1.0.0
but the error continues, whenever i attached agora_uikit plugin ,all the imports related to agora_rtc_engine started giving errors.[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just use the latest versions of each package?

Comment: i have downgraded the version of packages to match the compatibilities of them

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: error is in pubspec.yaml  in dependencies versions ,i provided both the error message and the pubspec.yaml 